# Installing Gnome 3 on Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, gnome, xubuntu

I have a few questions about this. I have Xubuntu 12.04 installed, using the default xfce, but I really like the look of Gnome 3. However, I always see people complaining about it. Would installing it on Xubuntu 12.04 be as simple as `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Or is it a different command, or what? Also, how stable is it? It looks really, really pretty, and I want to try it, but I don't want to end up screwing up my laptop.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP I want to say something. I have installed all Ubuntu Desktops almost in my Ubuntu ( Ubuntu,Kubuntu,Gnome,Xubuntu) and there is no any problem with my PC till now.

And yes we can install Gnome3 in Ubuntu with the command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome3
```

If you want to install it in GUI way then you can do it from software-center.

Comment: Raja, so you're saying that Gnome broke your ubuntu distros, or what..? I'm sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Nyaanbie I am saying that , Its completely safe to install Gnome in your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to install gnome-shell.
And it is as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: Okay, but that other guy's replies sort of confused me.. Does it effect the stability of my laptop? Like, is gnome prone to breaking or anything?

Comment: No, it is not going to break anything.

Comment: Also works (just verified) for **Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS**. *Once **gnome-shell** is installed, right click (on gear-icon) at login screen, and choose 'Ubuntu Classic'.*

Comment: Nothing is going to break.